# Does BIRT support Histogram

Tags: report, histogram, birt

I want to create Histogram in my Reports. I am using BIRT Reporting Template. Is there any way to create Histogram in BIRT. I checked in the palette of BIRT 3.7 and BIRT 4.3. But I dint find histogram options in the chart. Can we create Histogram using BAR chart? If yes, then what necessary changes we need to do in bar chart to look like Histogram?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should expand what you exactly have in mind for your histogram. In bar charts, there is an option which allows to remove space between bars:

Edit chart -> Format tab -> General properties -> unit space option (set to 0)

Here is the kind of chart we get, live sample [here](http://www.visioneo.org/and-much-more):

[image]